# mysql divison by zero error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use PHP to update column data but I am receiving a division by zero error.

```
mysql_query('UPDATE personas SET toolbar_id=\'' . $result . '\' WHERE download_ff LIKE concat('%',\'' . $result . '\','%')');
    echo mysql_error($link);
    printf("Records inserted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

Ive tried a few ways to concat the $result but it is all resulting in a division by zero error.  Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
concat('%',\'' . $result . '\','%')
```

The `%` ends out outside the string so PHP is interpreting it as a [modulus operation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and the strings on both sides of the modulus will be zeros in a numeric context, the result is that you're trying to `0 % 0` and you get your "division by zero" error.

Try escaping the inner single quotes:

```
concat(\'%\',\'' . $result . '\',\'%\')
```

Or, create a `$like_result` in your PHP that includes the percent signs in the string and then do this:

```
mysql_query('UPDATE personas SET toolbar_id=\'' . $result . '\' WHERE download_ff LIKE \'' . $like_result . '\';
```

You are using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) too, right?

Answer (score 1):

How about using single quotes for PHP and double quotes for SQL, that way you don't have to mess around with backslashes to escape quotes; using some whitespace also helps to make query better to read:

```
mysql_query( 
 'UPDATE personas SET 
   toolbar_id="' . $result . '" 
  WHERE 
   download_ff LIKE "%' . $result . '%" ' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Did not debug about the divistion by zero error. 
But your problem seems to be improper string formatting and concatenation,
PHP might be treating % as modulus operation with empty string ( i.e. 0 );

```
<?php

$a = 10;
$b = a%'';

?>   /* would give : Warning: Division by zero on line 4 */
```

Try the second version of the query, it would work :
http://codepad.org/6erRjYa7

```
<?php

$result = "foo";    
$query = $query = 'UPDATE personas SET toolbar_id=\'' . $result . '\' WHERE download_ff LIKE concat('%',\'' . $result . '\','%')';    
echo $query;

$queryNew =  "UPDATE personas SET toolbar_id='".$result."' WHERE download_ff LIKE concat('%','".$result."','%')";    
echo PHP_EOL ;
echo $queryNew;
?>
```